# How do I keep the most recent OPcache folder only?

Tags: php, server, opcache

I'm new to using OPcache on php 8 and I have some questions. So my folder structure looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb93u.png

Within each folder is the exact same thing, it's the structure of my website.

1. Why does OPcache generate multiple folders with the same content?
2. What is the best way to keep only the most recent folder and delete the others? Is there a check that can be done every so often or a setting that overwrites older files with new ones?

I'm fast approaching the file limit with my hosting and need to clear up some space.

I've read the docs but I don't have a lot of knowledge working with servers so any help is greatly appreciated!

Oh and these are the settings in my php.ini:

```
zend_extension=opcache.so;
opcache.enable=1;
opcache.memory_consumption=32;
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8;
opcache.max_accelerated_files=3000;
opcache.revalidate_freq=180;
opcache.fast_shutdown=0;
opcache.enable_cli=0;
opcache.revalidate_path=0;
opcache.validate_timestamps=1;
opcache.max_file_size=0;
opcache.file_cache=/mywebsitepath/.opcache;
opcache.file_cache_only=1;
```

Comment: From what I've read it sounds like a new cache dir will be generated when PHP is upgraded, so chances are your host is just keeping up with releases. You should be able to simply delete the old folders with no issue, eg: via a cron job such as `ls -t /mywebsitepath/.opcache/ | sed 1d | xargs rm -rf` [note: do not trust internet randos for things like this, test and verify yourself]

Comment: @Sammitch You are right about new directories being created with PHP upgrades. I did a test by upgrading myself and a new directory was created. I tried that command but it deleted everything in my OPcache folder. I don't understand the commands apart from ls and rm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has the same problem, this is what I ended up doing. First I tried to use the Wordpress cron manager but I was having issues getting a simple function to work. Instead, in my hosting you can create a cron job and link it to a php file, so I went that route instead. Here's the contents of the cron-jobs.php file which I put in my OPcache folder. Basically it sorts the folders by date modified then deletes the old ones while keeping the fresh one. If anyone has suggestions for improvements, be my guest!

```
function opcache_clean($dir) {
    $folders = array();

    foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {
        //we only want the folders, not files
        if ( strpos($file, '.') === false ) {
            $folders[$file] = filemtime($dir . '/' . $file);
        }
    }
    
    //only delete the old folders if there is more than one
    if (count($folders) > 1) {
        arsort($folders);
        $folders = array_keys($folders);
        //keep the first folder (most recent directory at index 0)
        $deletions = array_slice($folders, 1);
        
        foreach($deletions as $delete) {
            echo "deleting $delete <br>";
            system("rm -rf ".escapeshellarg($delete));
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "No folders to delete!";
    }
}

//clean the current directory
opcache_clean ( dirname(__FILE__) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it truly related but through trials and errors I've found that PHP revalidate and start whole opcache anew (making a new root directory for cache) after one make changes to the list of loaded extensions.  Recently I've added C-extension framework and PHP start caching from zero.